# How to create recurring event in Salesforce App (Salesforce 1)?

Tags: salesforce1-app, event

I have set the checkbox "Enable Creation of Recurring Events" in activity setting. I have also reviewed the Event Layout. Still I can't view "Recurrence" section in SF1 app. Strangely, it is visible in SF classic.

Is this feature not supported in SF1 app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform [specific](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_mobile_s1_newfeat_recurring_tasks.htm) actions to enable recurring tasks in Salesforce 1

> **Set Up Recurring Tasks for Salesforce1**
>
> Confirm these settings in Setup.
>
> - On the Activity Settings page, deselect the Show simpler New Task form
>     in Salesforce1 checkbox. The simpler New Task form doesn’t include the
>     options for creating a series of recurring tasks.
> - On your org’s Tasks
>     page layouts, the same settings that make recurring tasks available in
>     Lightning Experience are needed for Salesforce1.
>
>   1. Add the Create
>        Recurring Series of Tasks field to the Task Detail section of your
>        org’s Task page layouts.
>   2. If the Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience
>        Actions section on a Task page layout has been overridden, make sure
>        that the **Delete Series** and **View Series** actions from the Salesforce1 &
>        Lightning Actions palette are included in the section. Add these
>        actions if they’re not already there.